# What does the constant e in an R program output mean?

Tags: r

I wanted to know what the constant e in the R programme output means: 8.131e-02?

Answer (score 11):

It's the textual version of `10 to the power of`. e.g.

```
          -02
8.131 x 10     == 8.131e-02
```

Answer (score 6):

This is just the [E notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) of scientific notation.  See the link.

Answer (score 0):

R will give the output of 1e+06 rather than 1000000 because of the amount of characters that are used.

Look up scipen if you want to change the output.